# undefined reference to

Tags: qt, dll

Подключил .dll библиотеку к проекту. Затем сделал include .hpp библиотеки к main.cpp. Скопировал пример использования библиотеки и получил такие ошибки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include<com_pub.hpp>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    // include application headers
    #define NUM_OF_RETRIES 1
    GRC_TYPE RetCode;
    BOOLE bOpenAndRunning = FALSE;
    COM_BAUD_RATE cur=COM_BAUD_19200;
    // initialize GeoCOM
    RetCode = COM_Init();
    if (RetCode == GRC_OK)
    {
    // open a connection to the FlexLine instrument
    RetCode = COM_OpenConnection (COM_1, cur, NUM_OF_RETRIES);
    if (RetCode == GRC_OK)
    {
    bOpenAndRunning = TRUE;
    }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Вот .pro файл:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = untitled4
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS+=com_pub.hpp


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-untitled4-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/ -lGeoComS2K
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-untitled4-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/ -lGeoComS2K
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-untitled4-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/ -lGeoComS2K

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-untitled4-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-untitled4-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug
```

Comment: Ошибка линкера: он не может найти реализацию указанных функций. Статическую либу подключали?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов ,нет, библиотека состоит из .hpp .lib и .dll. В .pro файле выбрал добавить библиотеку и добавил .lib файл. затем нагуглил, что возможно .lib сделано msvs компилятором и надо переделать в .а.  скачал конвертер, повторил операции выше - так же ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте собрать из сорцов. Я в конвертер не верю.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, сорцов у меня нету, есть ли другие варианты решения?

Comment: Использование другого компилера

Comment: Не кладите .lib-файл в каталог сборки, потому что он может случайно удалиться при выполнении операции clean. Ошибка не должна быть связана с тем, что библиотека собрана в msvc, потому что она экспортирует только функции, а не классы. В этом случае все компиляторы собирают библиотеку одинаково. Если экспортируются классы, то начинаются непонятные преобразования имён.

Comment: @maestro, подключил библиотеку заново, теперь она в папке проекта, но ошибка не пропала(

Comment: @maestro, кстати, когда я компилировал в самый первый раз, мне выдало что в хедере библиотеки не определен HWND, пришлось в него добавить windows.h. может это повлияло? хотя вряд ли...

Comment: Проверьте разрядность библиотеки, операционной системы и вашей сборки.

Comment: Разве не должен линковщик сообщать об ошибке если библиотека ему не подходит?